# Are two triangles similar, if they have a common side, a common angle and have each one sides why is inverse proportional to the other?

Tags: geometry, triangles

I am just learning basics about geometry. My question is just the title:
Are the two triangles $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle XBC$ similar, if they share the side $BC$ and the angle $\angle XBC$ and if
$$\dfrac{|AB|}{|BC|}=\dfrac{|BC|}{|AX|}$$
is true. So the question is whether the side-angle-side criteria is also true, if two sides are inverse proportional. And if it is true (or not) why is it?

Comment: When $W$ is "just some constant", then certainly not: For any given positive $|AB|$ and $|AX|$, such $W$ exists.

Comment: I changed the question, but still thank you!!

Comment: How can the two triangles "share" angle $\angle XBC$ when $X$ is not in the first of the triangles at all?

Comment: Because $X$ lies on $BA$

Comment: I see. So essentially you're saying that CBX is a scaled _and mirrored_ version of ABC, and you're asking whether that counts as "similar"?

Comment: Apparently I do, I just don't understand why it is scaled and mirrored...

Comment: Hmm, it _would_ be scaled and mirrored if your equation had $|BX|$ in the lower right instead of $|AX|$. Was that what you intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The triangles *would* be similar if your proportionality were
$$ \frac{|AB|}{|BC|} = \frac{|BC|}{|BX|} $$
(note $|BX|$ instead of $|AX|$ in the lower right).

If that were the case, you could get $\triangle CBX$ from $\triangle ABC$ by:

1. Reflecting the triangle about the angle bisector of $\angle ABC$, and
2. Scaling the resulting triangle around $B$ by the factor $|BX|/|BC|$.

The first step swaps the *rays* $BA$ and $BC$; the scaling then (obviously) moves the reflected $C$ to $X$ and (by the assumption above) moves the reflected $A$ to $C$.

On the other hand, this means that if we actually have, as in the question,
$$ \frac{|AB|}{|BC|} = \frac{|BC|}{|AX|} $$
Then $\triangle CBX$ results from a triangle similar to $\triangle ABC$ by *moving just one of the points* along one of the sides it lies on. That only preserves similarity if nothing actually moved because $AX=BX$ -- that is, $X$ happens to be the midpoint of $AB$.

(You would also get similarity if the $X$ moves all the way out to $A$, of course -- but that would mean $|AX|=0$ which makes everything degenerate).